# Why are these responsive images not filling the wrapper?

Tags: html, css, responsive-images, srcset

I have a responsive image (srcset) that should be displayed at a max-width of 30rem, and fill the viewport otherwise. For that purpose I have the following html:

```
<div class="Wrapper">
  <img 
    src="//via.placeholder.com/250x150"           
    srcset="
      //via.placeholder.com/100x150 100w, 
      //via.placeholder.com/250x150 250w, 
      //via.placeholder.com/500x150 500w, 
      //via.placeholder.com/750x150 750w, 
      //via.placeholder.com/1000x150 1000w, 
      //via.placeholder.com/1250x150 1250w, 
      //via.placeholder.com/1500x150 1500w"
    sizes="(min-width: 30em) 30rem, 100vw"
  >  
</div>
```

With this css (there is more, but this is the minimum to reproduce):

```
html {
  font-size: 24px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.Wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 30rem;
  background: red;
}
```

On my monitor (macbook retina) the image is displayed like so:

[image: Demonstration of the problem]

So it isn't filling the viewport. Even though the measurements should be correct. I suspect that it has something to do with a difference in measurement between rem and em, but I'm not exactly sure what's going wrong. Why isn't the image filling the container?

Jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/Ly80zohd/2/

Comment: If you want to fill image you have to give `width:100%` to `img` tag but in that case image become stretch.

Comment: Of course, but if it would load the correct width I wouldn't have to do that. So I'm wondering why it isn't loading the correct width.

Comment: If you remove the `sizes` attribute, do you get the effect you want?

Comment: what browser if i may ask? and also have a look at this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683635/is-there-something-wrong-with-my-srcset-definition-or-is-current-browser-suppor/28684171#28684171

Comment: See [Device pixels vs. CSS pixels](https://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html)

Comment: @luciferous Chrome 62

Comment: @ovokuro Is that valid? Having srcset without sizes? But yeah, it does respond exactly the way I want it to.

Comment: It is valid without it. The `sizes` attribute will be set to `100vw` by default

Comment: @ovokuro Ok, actually that isn't exactly what I want. It's filling the container, but since it's defaulting to 100vw the images are sometimes way too big. Sort of defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently:

> - When used in `sizes` or media queries, `em` and `rem` are both specced to mean "the user's default `font-size`.
> - The actual `em` or `rem` that controls how the image is laid out on the page can end up different if your CSS changes it
> - This means one should *not* change the default size of `em` if they want to give the image preloader truthful information

So the em and rem in the `sizes` attribute do not correspond to the em and rem in your css. Which is why the size of the image doesn't correspond to its container. Ridiculous.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30675128/5918874

Comment: so this solves "But one strange thing i noticed was irrespecitve of the font-size specified for html , the 30em breakpoint was considered as 480px , i think that is because of the 16px base font size for html tag in chrome. (...investigation in progress:) ) " which i had said before :) ! Ty :D

Comment: @luciferous Yeah. It's so weird that they implemented it like this!

Answer (score 0):

May it help, Just remove below code from HTML and check it

```
sizes="(min-width: 30em) 30rem, 100vw"
```

Comment: It's not really an answer to my question. This doesn't answer the why.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the issue with image  not filling the container is concerned, i reckon it is because of the media-queries specified in `sizes` attribute.

Changing the media queries to something solid, say px measurements.

`sizes="(min-width: 376px) 80vw, 100vw"`

gives the proper behaviour.

But one strange thing i noticed was irrespecitve of the font-size specified for html , the `30em` breakpoint was considered as `480px` , i think that is because of the 16px base font size for html tag in chrome.*update above in OPs answer*

Also , i'd say if we were to use `srcset` with `w` units , it is beneficial to give `sizes` as the browser will decide which item to pick from srcset based on the conditions defined in `sizes` .

If one was to use pixel density units i.e `image-HD.jpeg 2x` , then we can skip the `sizes` attribute.

Further reading in this [excellent post about srcsets and sizes](https://ericportis.com/posts/2014/srcset-sizes/)

Comment: There should be no difference between the em and rem measurements though, as I'm setting the font-size on the html element. Also, changing the sizes attr to `(min-width: 30rem) 30rem, 100vw` doesn't solve it either. So this answer still doesn't help me figure out why Chrome isn't downloading images that fill the wrapper, even though the syntax indicates that it should (the `sizes` attr is correct and the necessary image sizes are available).